# Does iPod Touch 5th gen 16GB (mid 2013) still have built-in Camera app for use with front-facing camera?

Tags: applications, ipod-touch, camera

Recall: At the end of May, Apple introduced a lower-cost iPod Touch (5th generation, mid 2013) with just 16GB of storage, in one color (silver), no hand-strap, and no iSight rear-facing camera – but the front FaceTime camera remains.  So:

- Does this low-cost model of the iPod Touch 5th gen still ship with the iOS built-in "Camera" app, for use with the front-facing FaceTime camera that remains?

I'm asking because this is the first iOS device that has *only* a front-facing camera, and I'm not sure if it is for FaceTime *only*, or if the camera can still be used for stills and video (facing the user's direction, of course.)  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **yes** — the iPod touch 5th gen 16GB *does* still have the Camera app. Here's confirmation direct from Apple's recently-updated iPod touch manual:

- **[iPod touch User Guide - For iOS 6.1 Software (June 2013) [PDF]](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/ipod_touch_user_guide.pdf)**

In Chapter 9, **"Camera"**, on page 54, it states:

> With iPod touch, you can take both still photos and videos, using the
>   FaceTime camera on the front or the camera on the back (available on
>   some models).

There's also an accompanying image showing the built-in Camera app's user interface, and notes indicating controls for the flash and to "Switch between cameras" may not be available on some models:

---

[image: Apple iPod touch Camera app UI capture from manual]

---

Finally, I've also learned that third-party apps that use cameras on iOS devices should continue to function **provided** they use the iOS APIs *correctly* — as demonstrated in Apple sample code — to **query** the device for camera capability and the available cameras.  (When a third-party app assumes a rear-facing camera is *always* available on a camera-supporting device, such an app won't necessarily operate correctly on the iPod touch 5th gen 16GB.)